# Talend Data Itegration: Avoid nulls coming out of tExtractXMLField?

Tags: talend

I have this simple flow in Talend DI 6 (simplified for posting on SO):

[image]

The last step crashes with a NullPointerException, because missing XML attributes are returned as null.

Is there a way to get empty string values instead of nulls?

For now I'm using a tReplace step to remove nulls as a work-around, but it's tedious and adds to the cost of maintenance by creating one more place where the list of attributes needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In Talend DI 5.6.2 it is possible to add default data values to the schema. The column in the schema is called "Default". If you expect strings, you can set an empty string, which is set if the column value is null:

[Talend schema view with Default column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v40rD.png)

Works also for other data types. Talend DI 6 should still be able to do this, although the field might be renamed.